# Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly on apt-get install with no error

Tags: command-line, 16.04, apt, dpkg

I'm attempting to install unzip on Ubuntu 16.04.2. It takes a long time on the line `(Reading database...` with the percentage updating

I keep receiving the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  zip
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  unzip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 216 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/158 kB of archives.
After this operation, 530 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package unzip.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

No particular error message.

`dpkg --configure -a` and `dpkg -C` return nothing.

`apt-get clean` and `apt -f install unzip` do not help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on AWS on a t3.nano machine. The problem is that t3.nano only have 512MB of RAM. I believe it is not enough to perform the upgrade. I upgraded my instance to m5.large and was able to run the upgrade successfully.